# Issues with PHP Slim or API Generation

Tags: php, mysql, slim

i am new to using API's. i am using the Slim framework for PHP.
i have a data base called devdev and a table called product in mySQL.
I created a webpage, connected the database using normal PHP. and it displays my Products.

then i installed slim into my project and a few strange things happened.

the slim1.php file when opened in my browser displays exactly whats in my index.php. I am not sure why this is happening. the links to my login.php and register.php does not work either. when i click on the the URL changes to http:.../PHP/login.php but it still displays my index.php.

when i ran my slim1.php in thunder client it failed but when i ran index.php in thunder client it returned my index.php code. i am not sure why this is happening. i was expecting a JSON data format of my product list from my database. What is causing this to happen or what am i not getting/missing?

> slim1.php

```
   <?php

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require './vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;

// Running the Slim framework, Get Method
$app->get('/product', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    require_once 'db.php';// Calling the database connection file

    $query = "select * from devdev";// SQL query
    $result = $conn->query($query);

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $data[] = $row;// Store each field in an array
    }
    
    return json_encode($data);// Translate this array into JSON
});

$app->run(); //this ensures that the code runs in Slim
```

> index.php

```
 <?php 
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    session_start();
    include 'database.php';
    include 'cartProcess.php';
    include 'registerProcess.php';
    include 'loginProcess.php';
    
    // var_dump($_SESSION);


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta viewport="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Home Page</title>
            <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
            rel="stylesheet" 
            integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" 
            crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link href="../../FullStackOnlineStoreFinalCodespaceAcademy/CSS/styleHomePage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <link href="../../FullStackOnlineStoreFinalCodespaceAcademy/CSS/styleCart.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        </head>
```

> index.php "body"

```
<section>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <?php
                                $query = 'SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY id ASC';
                                $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                                        echo '
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <div class="card">
                                                <div class="card-body">
                                                    <form method="post" action="index.php?action=add&id='.$row['id'].'">
                                                        <div class="product">
                                                            <img src="'.$row['productImage'].'" alt="">
                                                            <h4 class="text-info">'.$row['productName'].'</h4>                                            
                                                            <h4 class="text-muted">'.$row['price'].' Coins</h4>
                                                            <p class="text-muted">'.$row['product description'].'</p>
                                                            <input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control" value="1">
                                                            <input type="hidden" name="productName" value="'.$row['id'].'">
                                                            <input type="hidden" name="price" value="'.$row['price'].'">
                                                            <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" class="btn btn-primary btn-block fa-lg gradient-custom-2 mb-3" value="Add to Cart">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </form>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        ';
                                    }
                                }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
```

Comment: `select * from devdev` makes no sense; mixing framework with clutter not either. I mean, when you run your queries in the template, why you even need a controller for that view ??

Comment: I dont understand what you mean :)

Comment: Just delete `index.php` and build it properly, with name-spacing and a framework.

Comment: SQL in HTML is not good. Please read the [Slim tutorial first](https://odan.github.io/2019/11/05/slim4-tutorial.html).